# Почему у меня нет команды localDateTime и других команд?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Почему отсутствуют множество команд в IntelliJ IDEA?

[image: нет большинства комманд]

Comment: Что такое "комманды в intelliJ idea"?  В показанном коде переменная `local` не определена, о чем и говорит ошибка `Cannot resolve symbol 'local'`.  Для использования класса `LocalDateTime` из пакета `java.time` нужно импортироватьт соответствующий пакет.

Comment: @Obito добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! Чтобы другие участники могли помочь вам, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1432546/edit) вопрос, напишите поподробнее, какие "команды" вы ожидаете увидеть? Из вашего вопроса не совсем ясно, что такое команда "localDateTime"? Напишите в самом вопросе, что эта команда должна делать? Нажмите кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1432546/edit) чтобы внести изменения в ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Имена классов в языке Java начинаются с прописной буквы. Чтобы Intellij IDEA подсказала вам, какие классы доступны в данном контексте, начните набирать текст с заглавной буквы: `Local` вместо `local`:

[image: скриншот]